# 403 Forbidden Error in django web server

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my application on webserver(django with apache2 and mod_wsgi). But i got 403 forbidden error while running the site..(Forbidden 
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 104.131.127.196 Port 80). The structure of my web application looks as:

```
CASINOVA
|-- Casinova
|   |-- db.sqlite3
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- manage.py
|   |-- casinova
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |   |-- settings.py
|   |   |-- settings.pyc
|   |   |-- urls.py
|   |   |-- urls.pyc
|   |   |-- wsgi.py
|   |   `-- wsgi.pyc
|   `-- static
```

## sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Alias /static /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova/static/
<Directory /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova/static>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess Casinova python-path=/var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova:/var/www/html/CASINOVA/venv/Casinova/lib/python2.7/si$
WSGIProcessGroup Casinova
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova/casinova/wsgi.py

ServerName 0.0.0.0
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

## sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
ServerName mydomain.com
```

## vi /etc/hosts.py

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
104.131.127.196 Casinova
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

#ls -l /var/www/html

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 Mar 29 08:42 CASINOVA
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11510 Mar 30 03:05 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    20 Oct 28 01:42 info.php
```

i have posted the contents from the files default.conf, apache2.conf and hosts.py. What is the mistake in that??

Comment: Have a look at `tail -n 50 /var/log/apache2/error.log`, it will gives you hint on what permissions is missing.

Comment: The error was "Options ExecCGI is off in this directory". I have cleared it by replacing "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI" with Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews.. But same forbidden error occurs @Cyrbil

Comment: @shalin Probably a stupid question. How can one create the django project structure like in the first code sample in your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova/static>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My guess, set ExecCGI for your Django directory, not for `/static`.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/CASINOVA/Casinova>
Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```